Can i apply for Germany Family reunion visa along with my husband
My daughter and I live in India and my husband is working in Portugal. His company is ready to provide him work in Germany. We wanted to move to Germany in Family Reunion Visa. I saw in Germany embassy website that spouse can also apply family reunion along with the other member (work permit visa). My questions are as below:

Is it not necessary for him to have a blue card if we both apply at the same time from India.(husband for work visa myself and the child for Family reunion visa)
If he applies from Portugal to Germany work visa then i have to wait until he gets a blue card and then apply for Family reunion from India. IS my understanding correct in this case?

